# Program that lets a user search a file for words

Tags: c, file

I'm attempting to create a program that lets the user enter words and then the program searches the file for the entered word. I believe what happens in my program however is that as I enter the words it doesn't start over at 0 of the char array I'm entering it into

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int num =0;
char word[2000];
char *string;

FILE *in_file = fopen("words.txt", "r");
//FILE *out_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");

if (in_file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error file missing\n");
    exit(-1);
}

while(word[0]!= '0')
{
    printf("please enter a word(enter 0 to end)\n");
    scanf("%s",word);

    while(!feof(in_file))
    {
        fscanf(in_file,"%s",string);
        if(!strcmp(string,word))//if match found
        num++;
    }
    printf("we found the word %s in the file %d times\n",word,num );
    num = 0;
}

return 0;
 }
```

Can someone help me so that it rereads into the correct position? So that when it goes to compare the words it does so correctly?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15508828/509868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare memory for `char *string;`. Your program tries to write with `fscanf(in_file,"%s",string);` in unreserved memory causing *undefined behavior* and then very likely a crash.

Replace `char *string;` with `char string[ MAX_WORD_LENGTH ]`

There are many other problems, for example your search might only work on the first try since you are reading the file every time and once you hit EOF you won't read any more. You should set the position indicator to the beginning of the file with [fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) on every search.

```
fseek ( in_file, 0, SEEK_SET );
```

Also using [*strstr*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) instead of *strcmp* might produce better results.

Comment: ? on my end the program runs for one word correctly and then returns 0 for every word entered after the first i dont get any crashes this also doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @undone98, crashes are not the only possible result of undefined behavior.  Fix it because this issue could be the potential cause of just about any symptom you might report.