# Count all character occurrences in a text file

Tags: c, file, for-loop, while-loop

The following code snippet is intended to count all the symbols met in a file after text is entered, next step is counting the occurrences of all characters (For instance 'a' met 3 times, 'b' 0 times etc.). However when I compile the loop goes infinite and the counting is always 0. My question is if it could be fixed or rewritten in another way.

```
char type, c, text[100]; counts[100];
int count=0, i;

while((type=getchar())!=EOF) {
    fputc(type, f); count++;
}

printf("Symbols found: %d", count-1);
rewind(f);

while(fscanf(f, "%s", &text)) {
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        counts[(text[i])]++;
        printf("The %d. character has %d occurrences.\n", i, counts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `size`?

Comment: Why don't you count the characters during the first `getchar()` loop?

Comment: Character codes go higher than 100.

Comment: You shouldn't be printing the counts in the same loop that's adding them up. You need to add up all the counts first, then do another loop that prints the count for each character.

Comment: Why do you print out the occurences for e.g. the first 10 characters when you read a 10-character string (in the `for`)?

Comment: You need to start over, and think about what you're doing. In your printf, you're using `i` when you should be printing `text[i]`.

Comment: @Barmar: He's not counting character codes, he is only concerned with the first 100 characters he encounters.

Comment: @GIJoe `text[i]` is a character code, so `counts[text[i]]++` is counting the number of occurrences of that character code.

Comment: @Barmar: He is reading in a file with `fscanf`, it loads the stream into the `string` called text. Essentially, it looks for a string and loads it into text, such as abcdefgh

Comment: And each element of a string is a character, which is a small integer containing the character code.

Comment: @Barmar: Right, but he's not looking at only Character codes up to 100 as you implied in your comment from 26 mins ago, only 100 characters. He is getting the index into the string. There are more problems with that loop such as to ensure that he doesn't blow up or go out of bounds, but he is not looking at up to 100 character codes, just 100 things

Comment: But he declared `counts[100]`. If there's an `i` in the text, that's 105, and he'll do `counts[105]++`, which goes outside the array bounds. I don't see where he's limiting his reading to the first 100 characters in the text. If any of the words have more than 100 characters, `fscanf` will exceed the bounds of `text[100]`.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I acknowledge that he will blow up his array if he tries to consume a string larger than 100 characters. However, that has nothing to do with character codes and more to do with the length of a string.

Comment: There are two different arrays that are declared as length 100. My first comment was about `counts[100]`. This is indexed by character codes, so it needs to be `counts[256]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program to read words from a file and count their occurrence in the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508828/program-to-read-words-from-a-file-and-count-their-occurrence-in-the-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can build your histogram as you read the input.  The return value from `getchar()` is an `int`, not a `char`, since it has to represent `EOF` in addition to the 256 `char` values.  Once the histogram has been built, you can iterate over the buckets and print them.  Here, I have assumed that all 256 `char` values are possible, and included code to display unprintable characters in hex notation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    int i;
    int histogram[256];
    int total;

    memset(histogram, 0, sizeof(histogram));
    total = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        histogram[c]++;
        total++;
    }

    printf("Symbols found: %d\n", total);

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (histogram[i]) {
            char repr[5];
            sprintf(repr, isprint(i) ? "%c" : "\\x%02x", i);
            printf("The '%s'. character has %d occurrences.\n", repr, histogram[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop scans the string with variable `i` being an index to the character tested, but your `printf` says `i` is a symbol accounted.
You should separate counting and printing results:

```
char * ptr;

while(fscanf(f, "%s", text))
   for (ptr = text; * ptr != 0; ptr++)
       counts[ (unsigned char)*ptr ]++;

for( i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    printf("The %d. character has %d occurrences.\n", i, counts[i]);
```

Don't forget to declare `count[ 256]` and note that `scanf` gets `text`, not `&text~as a destination.