# Count occurrences of each word in a text file

Tags: c, algorithm, file, data-structures, hashtable

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int word_count()
{
    FILE *p;
    char ch;
    int w = 0;
    p = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        ch = fgetc(p);
        while (ch != EOF)
        {
            if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
            {
                w++;
            }
            ch = fgetc(p);
        }
        return w;
    }
    fclose(p);
}

void main()
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char ch;
    void *p;
    int i, n;
    w = word_count()

        fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf("Words\t\t occurrences\t\n);
            exit(0);
    }
    fp1 = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            ch = fgetc(f1);
            p = &ch;
            p++;
            while (ch != EOF)
            {
                while (strcmp(ch, *p) == 0)
                {
                    n++;
                    p++;
                }
                fputc(ch, fp2);
                fputc(n, fp2);
            }
        }
        ch++;
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}
```

I've been asked by my professor to write a c code that would read a file and find the occurrences of each word. here's the code i tried but it requires that I use something better than pointers, may be a hashtable and keep track of all the words and count their occurrences.
I'm having trouble choosing the right datastructures and since im just a beginner, i need help choosing the datastructures.

Comment: Can you list approaches or datastructures you have in mind? Do you know pros and cons of each approach? memory requirement, execution time, ease to implement etc.

Comment: I would consider creating two functions. One where you would go through your file once and store all of the words and the other to count the number of occurrences of each of the words.

Comment: @MohitJain I thought of using hash tables but I'm unsure of what else can be used. I also thought of using stacks or linked list. Problem with pointers or comparing each word will yield to time complexities i believe [O(n)]

Comment: @Module thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that

Comment: @Harshithaks I have no idea how stacks can be useful here. But storing each word in a linked list, or hash or a trie sounds plausible. Everytime search for the new word, if it is present in the list, increment the count. If not insert it. (inserted sorted in case of linked list)

Comment: @Harshithaks You can use this link if you need some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508828/program-to-read-words-from-a-file-and-count-their-occurrence-in-the-file

Comment: You could just store the words in a list. Then sort the list so that duplicates are grouped together (i.e. all usages of "the" will be together). Then you just go through the list and count the occurrences of each word.

Comment: @Module thanks for the link but it does not take the file as an input,but asks for the user to enter a string.That's not what I want to do.

Comment: @JimMischel thank you. I'll try that