# C, conflicting types on a function that takes in chars and returns chars when it's been declared already? Then sudden loop only supported in c99

Tags: c, pointers, encryption

I am getting these two following error messages on 2 parts of the code that's been marked as comments.

But why do these error messages happen? I have declared the decrypt function before main haven't I? and is this not how you implement a for loop in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conf.h>
#include <evp.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
unsigned char *readWord(FILE *fp);
char *decrypt(unsigned char *Ciphertext, unsigned char *key,unsigned char *iv);
int main (void)
{
    char *key = NULL;
    char *iv = "aabbccddeeff00998877665544332211";
    char *Plaintext = "This is a top secret.";
    char *Ciphertext = "764aa26b55a4da654df6b19e4bce00f4ed05e09346fb0e762583cb7da2ac93a2";
    char *checker;

    FILE *words = (fopen("words", "r"));

    while(1) {
        key = readWord(words);
        if (!key){
            printf("the key was not found");
            break;
        }
        else{
            checker = decrypt(Ciphertext,key,iv);
            if(strcmp(checker,Plaintext)){
                printf("the correct key is ");
                printf(key);
            }
            free(key);
            free(checker);

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

char *decrypt(unsigned char *Ciphertext, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv) //here it's correctly declared right?
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx; //could not be resolved not sure why
    unsigned char *plainText = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 64);

    int len;
    int plaintext_len;

    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors(); //why error here it's fine below


    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))

        handleErrors();


    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plainText, &len, Ciphertext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
        plaintext_len += len;


    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plainText + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    int checkLen = (2 * len) + 1;
    char *checker2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (checkLen));
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) //for loop only allowed in C99 mode what?
    {
        sprintf(checker2 + (i*2),"%02x",plainText[i]);
    }
    free(plainText);


    return checker2;
}
```

This is the complete error messages on the console.

```
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "Cygwin GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
make all 
'Building file: ../src/try.c'
'Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler'
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/try.d" -MT"src/try.o" -o "src/try.o" "../src/try.c"
../src/try.c: In function 'main':
../src/try.c:30:10: warning: pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
../src/try.c:36:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'decrypt' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
../src/try.c:18:7: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'char *'
../src/try.c:36:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'decrypt' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
../src/try.c:18:7: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'char *'
../src/try.c:36:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of 'decrypt' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
../src/try.c:18:7: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'char *'
../src/try.c: In function 'decrypt':
../src/try.c:59:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'handleErrors' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
../src/try.c:67:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'EVP_DecryptUpdate' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from ../src/try.c:13:0:
c:\users\marcu\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/evp.h:635:5: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'char *'
../src/try.c:72:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'EVP_DecryptFinal_ex' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
In file included from ../src/try.c:13:0:
c:\users\marcu\gcc\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/evp.h:638:5: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'char *'
../src/try.c:80:5: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
../src/try.c:80:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [src/try.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: What is unclear with the compiler message? The compiler issues messages specially for you.

Comment: Allowing the first clause of the `for` loop to be a declaration is a feature that was added in the 1999 version of the C standard (a.k.a. C99). It seems the compiler you are using assumes an earlier standard by default (probably C89/C90).

Comment: `Ciphertext` is a `char*` but `decrypt` expects an `unsigned char*`. What's unclear here? Same for the other warnigs.

Comment: `implicit declaration of function 'handleErrors' ` is also self explanatory. You didn't declare `handleErrors`. When you see a warning containing the word `implicit`, consider it as an error.

Comment: @Jabberwocky nothing changes if I change the variables it to unsigned char.

All I get are 12 more errors etc.

Comment: @jondoe: 12 more errors is a change and is a different problem. Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging or tutorial service. It is not for helping you keep making changes to your program until you get it right. Each post is for one specific question. It is up to you to research and understand the problem you are facing well enough to ask a useful question. You should be isolated your problems to one specific thing to ask about, posed with a [mre].

Comment: There is some misleading indentation on one of the `plaintext_len += len;` lines.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Late reply but, I am aware of that I was just making a comment about what happened later.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because declaring variables inside a for loop wasn't valid C until C99(which is the standard of C published in 1999), you can either declare your counter outside the for as pointed out by others or use the -std=c99 flag to tell the compiler explicitly that you're using this standard and it should interpret it as such.

You can init i variable like this.

```
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) //for loop only allowed in C99 mode what?
    {
        sprintf(checker2 + (i*2),"%02x",plainText[i]);
    }
```

Comment: That's answers only one part of the question. And it's merely a repetition of one of the comments

Comment: Well thanks that takes care of 1 problem, but... as I said previously in a comment, changing everything to unsignes char I am now stuck on the code having an error on reading the file.

Comment: @jondoe _having an error on reading the file._: what uis that suppsed to mean? Have an error can be anything from a slightly different result what you expect to setting your house on fire. Maybe you shouls ask another question about that specific problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky unrefered reference to read word

Comment: @jondoe Is there a "words" file in the directory where the program is launched from? You can also change mode from "r" to "a". The main difference is that mod 'a' will create the file if it doesn't exist

Comment: @jondoe you didn't create the readWord function either, you can see in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508828/program-to-read-words-from-a-file-and-count-their-occurrence-in-the-file) how to create it

Comment: @semyon wait....  C does not have inbuilt functions of reading files? I must code it myself rom scratch?

Comment: @jondoe it's have but this functions works not like you want. You can try use `fread`. more info [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)

Comment: @Semyon Well thank you this is a start. One problem got solved and I got a head start on what to focus on now I guess.

Comment: @Semyon Wait since varibles inside C wasn't unitl C99 as you said does this mean other parts of the code might not work depending of wich version I am using?

Comment: @jondoe all parts of the code will work, if this is not the case, the compiler will definitely notify you. New versions usually contain only small simplifications when writing code, there are no major changes that change the logic. 

I also noticed an error that you might have missed, you did not allocate memory for the `key` variable, as you did for `checker2`, this can cause a memory leak

Comment: @Semyon Ok, this is a bit helpfull to know but I do have one following question about the code.

I cannot figure out why I get the error message on EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx. I am making an object using the EVP.H file right? I mean they are included from the H file along with everything else EVP_CIPHER related. 

even looking at the openSSL site this is how they implement things.